# store uncertain order of list item in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

this is the front-end http://jsfiddle.net/JRwM7/2/

I thought of just insert normally (using `order by`) then do the sorting in the front-end, but I curious and wanted to know is there any method of query to have a sorted data in my db table.

Comment: Unless you have a specific column that is applies some sort of order, order makes no sense for insertion into a db table.

Comment: I want to insert all the data into 1 table

Answer (score 0):

A table is a **set** (of rows), and sets are inherently unordered. Logically, the only way to guarantee an order of rows returned from some query is to use ORDER BY clause.

On the physical level, if ORDER BY clause happens to match an index, the DBMS might be able to establish the order by just traversing the index's B-Tree instead of performing a separate sort, which may benefit performance.

> insert normally (using order by)

I'm not sure what you mean by that? ORDER BY is not valid syntax for INSERT INTO.

Comment: oh I typed something wrong. I should say even I couldn't retrieve the data with order by, for example select * from tableN....order by.....it seem like I just insert or retrieve as usual and sort them in front-end